# "IN" command's AND logical operator counterpart?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have 2 tables:

- Employee
- EmpLocXref

If I wanted to list employees that belong to locations 1, 2, **or** 3 I would write a query similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, e.name
FROM Employee e
JOIN EmpLocXref x ON x.employee_id = e.id
WHERE x.location_id IN (1, 2, 3)
;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01539d/1/0).

But what if I wanted to list employees that only belong to locations 1, 2, **and** 3?  I realize I could write something similar to:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM Employee e
JOIN EmpLocXref x ON x.employee_id = e.id
WHERE x.location_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01539d/2/0)

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't include dynamic SQL?

EDIT: Fixed derp moment on 2nd query.  Added Fiddler examples.

Comment: Which DBMS?  Also, is your list of filter values static or dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic, the actual query uses a stored procedure and passes in a table value parameter to JOIN off of in TSQL2012.  Above is just a simplified version of the problem.

Comment: Would AND not return no rows for two values or more, since there's no way for a column to simultaneously have two values?

Comment: Are you looking for Employees at all locations or only certain locations?

Comment: @ypercube Ah, yes.  Of course.... (deleted my comment)

Comment: `WHERE x.location_id = 1 OR x.location_id = 2 OR x.location_id = 3`

Comment: Edited original post to fix 2nd query

Comment: You've almost got it now.  Instead of `WHERE x.location_id IN (1, 2, 3)` just join the table-valued parameter with the list of `Location_ID`s.  Then replace `COUNT(*)=3` with `COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(*) from TVP tvp1)` where TVP is your table-valued parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The above actually wouldn't work, because you'd never have a record in EmpLocXref where the location_id is 1 and 2 and 3 all at the same time.  You'd get zero results.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmpLocXref x1 ON e.ID = x1.EmployeeID AND x1.Location_id = 1
INNER JOIN EmpLocXref x2 ON e.ID = x2.EmployeeID AND x2.Location_id = 2
INNER JOIN EmpLocXref x3 ON e.ID = x3.EmployeeID AND x3.Location_id = 3
```

Comment: Good answer (just got in before me!) for a static list of `Location_id`s but the OP also wanted this to work with a dynamic list from a table-valued parameter.